# Update reference in Google Sheets formula when a form adds new rows

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

Using help from various sources and bits of a formula taking data from different Google Sheets columns, I now have the following formula for calculating some numerical totals.  I cant get it to update and move down when new data rows are added.

```
=SUMIF(D2:D105,C108,E2:E106)
```

I know its something like this which I have elsewhere but I just don-t know how to combine them.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("E2:E"&ROW()-1))
```

So I essentially want the first formula to update as new rows are added.

Comment: Does it work to just reference the entire column? `=SUMIF(D:D,C108,E:E)`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I pasted that in but got a #REF error.  Where would the Row -1 need to fit into the first formula?

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want one formula in one cell that gives you a sum or do you want a  formula to copy / paste into a bunch of cells (probably in a column)?

Comment: Thank you!  Its a single formula pasted into one cell which draws on data from a number of other cells and will calculate a sum when a new row is added

Comment: Wow that looks complicated but sounds like what I am after. After pasting into blank cell I get a #Name  error  not recognising LET   - not sure if its because Im in GoogleSheets? Ive temporarily shared a link to document (its a learning points logbook)  the totals and formulas near bottom and I need the Internal and External totals to change when a Google Form entry adds a new entry row.       https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VEOOrzLwiXJy1Pt_wMcodySkdTsBjE7Fz0I4ukUIveM/edit

Comment: I think the revised answer will help. Welcome to SuperUser, by the way. A few extra tips: 1) In general, don't publicly share your real data because of privacy / confidentiality concerns and also the risk of trolls. 2) Google Sheets and Excel are much alike but different enough that it matters. Be sure to tag the right one in your question. 3) I wouldn't recommend using the form results tab in Sheets for *anything* except form responses. You can move all those formulas to another tab, change your references to the entire column (`C:C` or, in Sheets, `C2:C`) and it'll work fine.

Comment: Thank you. Comments noted. Will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The original answer is invalidated by OP stating they are using Google Sheets, not Excel. The revised answer based on that and the sharing of their sheet is here:

You need to replace the range references in the top formula (`D2:D105` and `E2:E106`) with something like this snippet from the second formula:

```
INDIRECT("E2:E"&ROW()-1)
```

`INDIRECT()` lets you input a string and it will be converted to a range. The text `E2:E` gives you most of the range but it still needs that second row number. `ROW()` returns the row of a cell. If you don't tell it which cell to use, it uses the same cell the formula is in. `ROW()-1`, then, gives you the row above your cell. Having now seen your sheet, you just need to adjust the `-1` to be whatever is appropriate based on where the formula is relative to the end of your data.

---

---

---

The best option depends on how your data is setup.

---

**Reference the entire column:**

```
=SUMIF(D:D,C108,E:E)
```

This will always capture everything which will automatically include any new data at the bottom. You should not place this formula in either of the impacted columns (ie, don't put it anywhere in column D or E).

You said in the comments that you tried this and got a `#REF!` error. This likely means that some cell in column D or E is a `#REF!` error. If you try to reference an error in a formula, that formula also returns an error. Look for a cell with an error in it and, if you find one / many, correct it / them.

---

**Go from row 2 to the first blank row:**

```
=LET(blankRow,ROW(INDEX(D:D,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((D:D<>0),0),0))),SUMIF(INDIRECT("D2:D"&blankRow),C108,INDIRECT("E2:E"&blankRow)))
```

This got complicated but let's take out a big piece:

```
LET(blankRow,ROW(INDEX(D:D,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((D:D<>0),0),0))),...
```

The `LET()` function lets you take some big formula and give it a short name. Our big formula is `ROW(INDEX(...))` and it finds the first blank row in a given range. That's why I gave it the name `blankRow`. This formula looks in `D:D` but you could change it to look in `E:E` if you prefer. Now that we know what that is, let's look at the second piece:

```
...SUMIF(INDIRECT("D2:D"&blankRow),C108,INDIRECT("E2:E"&blankRow)))
```

That looks a little more familiar. It references columns D and E but only the rows from `2` to `blankRow`. The `INDIRECT()` function takes a string version of a range address and turns it into a range. As you add data to the bottom, `blankRow` from the first half will get bigger so the range references in the second half will grow accordingly.

---

**Go from row 2 to the last non-blank row**

```
=LET(nonBlankRow,SUMPRODUCT(MAX((D:D<>"")*ROW(D:D))),SUMIF(INDIRECT("D2:D"&nonBlankRow),C108,INDIRECT("E2:E"&nonBlankRow)))
```

Same basic idea. The first half defines the last non-blank row to be called `nonBlankRow`:

```
=LET(nonBlankRow,SUMPRODUCT(MAX((D:D<>"")*ROW(D:D))),...
```

The second half gets a sum based on the ranges from row 2 to that last non-blank row:

```
...SUMIF(INDIRECT("D2:D"&nonBlankRow),C108,INDIRECT("E2:E"&nonBlankRow)))
```

Comment: Perfect thank you!